# html form does not fire javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have following form and javascript which is not activated on submit. I can not understand where is the problem so that the javascript is not fired by pressing the button. The script is included in the html of course and the path is correct.

```js
var req;

function addProductToCart(){
  var url = "/addToCart";
  var productReference = document.getElementById("selectedProductRef");
  var size = document.getElementById("selectedProductSize");
  req = initRequest();
  req.open("POST", url, true);
  //req.onreadystatechange = callback;
  req.send("selectedProductRef="+productReference.value+"&selectedProductSize="+size.value);
}

function callback(){
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
    if (req.status == 200) {
      parseMessages(req.responseText);
    }
  }
}

function initRequest(){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject){
    // code for IE6, IE5
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="addToShoppingBag" id="addToShoppingBag" >
  <input type="hidden"
         form="addToShoppingBag"
         id="selectedProductRef"
         name="selectedProductRef"
         value="${selectedCart.productReference}">
  <input type="button"
         form="addToShoppingBag"
         name="addToCart"
         id="addToCart"
         onclick="addProductToCart()"
         class="css-button primary"                         
         value="ADD TO SHOPPING BAG">
</form>
```

Comment: Inline events are ugly and poor practice -- attach your events with javascript!

Comment: Also, check the console. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined`

Comment: req.open("POST", url, true); this what function?

Comment: A few other problems: 1) You are defining `req` as the return value from `initRequest()`, but you're not returning anything from `initRequest()` 2) There is no element `#selectedProductSize`.

Comment: You are setting `req = initRequest()` but init request does not return the XHR object, so it's undefined.

Comment: SelectedProductSize exists is an input element which I have not copied here but is related to the form

Comment: With the debugger I set a breaking point in the function addProductToCart() but I see that pressing the button does not enter the function

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/) a nice blog post on why to move away from using inline javascript.

You might want to consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) as a way to facilitate going to a more event-driven scripting approach. It also makes async requests pretty straight-forward with its `$.ajax()` method.

Here's your `addProductToCart()` in jQuery format:

```
$('body').on('click', '#addToCart', ({
  var url = "/addToCart";
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: '{selectedProductRef: "'+ $('#selectedProductRef').val() + '", selectedProductSize:"' + $('#selectedProductSize').val() + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var req;

    function addProductToCart(){
      var url = "/addToCart";
      var productReference = document.getElementById("selectedProductRef");
   productReferenceValue =productReference ;
   var size = document.getElementById("selectedProductSize");
    sizeValue=size .value;

      rm = initRequest();
      rm.open("POST", url, true);
      //req.onreadystatechange = callback;
      rm.send("selectedProductRef="+productReferenceValue +"&selectedProductSize="+size.sizeValue);
    }

    function callback(){
      if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
          parseMessages(req.responseText);
        }
      }
    }

    function initRequest(){
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       return new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else if (window.ActiveXObject){
        // code for IE6, IE5
       return  new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <form name="addToShoppingBag" id="addToShoppingBag" >
      <input type="hidden"
             form="addToShoppingBag"
             id="selectedProductRef"
             name="selectedProductRef"
             value="${selectedCart.productReference}">
      <input type="button"
             form="addToShoppingBag"
             name="addToCart"
             id="addToCart"
             onclick="addProductToCart()"
             class="css-button primary"                         
             value="ADD TO SHOPPING BAG">
    </form>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: I am afraid the form does not call the function. In the <head> section of the HTML I have included <script src="js/minicart.js"></script>

Comment: yes I tried it with anothe function and i have other scripts in the same location included with the same path. Is something wrong with the form?

Comment: Do you mean to import the java in the html?

Comment: Yes try write javasript code in html and try worked your code?

Answer (score 0):

A little change in your code instead of  `req = initRequest();` just call `initRequest()`

```
  var size = document.getElementById("selectedProductSize");
  initRequest();
  req.open("POST", url, true);
```

`initRequest()` does not return any value.